# How well does this question follow community guidelines

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

The question in question [How to set up Flex Unit 4.2 without Flash Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37428734/how-to-configure-flex-unit-4-2-in-without-flash-builder/37431490#37431490).
This question is:

- Concise
- Shows research effort
- Has an accurate title
- Relates specifically to programming using a very well known library

Here is a possible violation from the help centre:

> 4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
>      library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
>      Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>      Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
>      it.

In the question that was asked, resources are explicitly mentioned in a context of having a lack of information about the configuration/setup required for the specific library.

In the context of SO's community guidelines, is this question a question that adds value to programmers finding solutions for programming related problems?

Comment: The question, though you linked the answer, is an off-topic resource request that people will happily close as such.

Comment: It would help users to understand why it is an off-topic resource request if further explanation could be given.

Comment: There are links under the close reason to the Help Center. Most people that register for the site probably plow right into asking questions before getting a feel for things or taking the tour. Under the close reason you could find after a few clicks [1](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and [2](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and a link to [this](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) and to [this](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#idm45835691726848) that says "A:

The same place I'd find it, &#^D— at the other end of a web search. "

Comment: There are a boat-load of reasons things close. There is no lack of info if one reads around.

Comment: @Drew Despite having read around, I still can't see why specifically this question should be closed

Comment: Let's take your current version. Just like the previous one, I am fine up until the last paragraph. In that last paragraph you are asking for others to point you toward documentation that you cannot find. That is a resource request. Let's say the last paragraph is ditched and somehow it has a nice ending to it. Others may close it for "setup my environment" close reasons. Is that more clear? Note, we want you to get an answer, right? It is not like people want to stifle knowlege sharing. But the site agreed to changes a while back as to what is appropriate for the site. Not everyone agrees

Comment: Guidelines do have a knack for being applied inappropriately.  You can read almost anything you want into that question, it is concise to a fault.  But I'm seeing a programmer that doesn't mind solving his own problem.  How refreshing.

Comment: @Drew As an experienced SO user, perhaps you can help me edit that last part. I attempt to allow the answerer to find the best possible solution, which is identified as a positive quality in the links you've mentioned to communicate the approaches already taken in as few words as possible.

Comment: @Drew In regards to the "setup my environment" reading of the question - I don't understand how the Flash Builder wizard works. I need to include some Flex Unit specific classes and connect them in a specific way. In order to actually do the unit testing, I don't know the tests are setup and run without the magic wizard of Flash Builer. Cheers for the help.

Comment: @cdilga I have done my best with an edit. I assume you have seen the section [If you are using ActionScript 3 Only](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLEX/FlexUnit+Getting+Started) and wish you luck with finding someone that has done this configuration. Flash Builder was once a passion of mine, as short-lived as it was.

Comment: @Drew Cheers with the edit. I have seen that as3 only section, and I believe I have found an as3 only .swc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question itself is not specifically off topic. It is asking a question about using a programming environment in a certain scenario and that doesn't mean it is asking for an off site resource.

Some of the downsides are the poor grammar, lack of a detailed "here is what I know, here is what I don't know" description, and mainly that the user did not search.

Community guidelines are to look for existing material prior to posting. I think we all agree on this, and a long time ago at a meta far far away the highest voted point for what Stack Overflow was not was a research assistant.

As a user, I should not have to go figure out how to find the correct google result for someone. But in light of that, here I am finding the correct google result, which happened to be a Stack Overflow post, and is also a duplicate.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1445064/1026459

So from a "follows community guidelines" angle I would go with a gracious 4/10.

Comment: Note that the correct answer actually provides additional information not mentioned in the question that was just identified as a duplicate. The questions also identify different issues, OP's link is AS3 specific and thus is not answered by the MXMLC question.

Comment: *...the downsides is the poor grammar...* Oh irony! :)